# Gerar sql a partir de um retorno de um js

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, jquery-datatables

Bom dia galera do stack overflow.
Já faz algum tempo que venho martelando para procurar uma solução para um problema que apareceu, que não vem nada na cabeça.

Eu tenho um form, onde esse form vai fazer um filtro em datatable do js.
Esse datatable eu uso ele serverside, então preciso de querys sql. 
Até ai tudo bem, o problema começa com o retorno que recebo no php.

Ele é um retorno que pode variar de acordo com o que tenho no form.
Ai que começa meu problema, esse retorno variando.

Pode chegar assim no php: `Desistência de Cadastro,Carta Negada,Carta Cancelada,,,,`

Como pode chegar dessa mesma forma também.

`Cadastro Iniciado,Aguardando aprovação de cadastro,Cadastro Aprovado,Carta Solicitada,Desistência de Cadastro,Carta Negada,Carta Cancelada,,,MS,MG,PA,PB,PR,PE,PI,RJ,RN,RS,RO,RR,SC,SP,`

A pergunta é: como gerar um sql a partir desses valores.

A query vai ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
   SELECT id_parceiro, nome_empresa, cidade, estado, status_atual, ultima_data, data_anterior, status_anterior, dias_entre_status
        FROM  report_partner_view WHERE ativo = 1
        AND (status_atual = 'Cadastro Iniciado' OR status_atual = 'Carta Negada')
        ORDER BY  id_parceiro
                    asc
        LIMIT 0, 10
```

Sendo esse AND, OR, por estado, status, sendo formado pelo retorno mostrado a cima.

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: o retorno do status é sempre 1 desses citados certo ?

Comment: Sim... são sempre esses: Cadastro Iniciado, 
Aguardando aprovação de cadastro, 
Cadastro Aprovado, 
Carta Solicitada, 
Desistência de Cadastro, 
Carta Negada,
Carta Cancelada

Comment: entao com seu problema é com o retorno do status vc precisa fazer um select com base nele e no estado é isso ?

Comment: Sim, na verdade, tudo que pode vim, são os estados, esses status, 2 datas e um campo de cidade... vou ter que montar um select com base neles

Comment: Eu imagino que se eu for comparando um por um, seja gambiarra, tem forma de fazer isso dinamicamente?

Comment: não consegui entender bem a sua dificuldade, mas isso nao resolveria ?
status_atual = '. $retorno .' OR estado= '. $retorno .'

Comment: Vou iniciar um chat

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57291/discussion-between-gabrielfalieri-and-jefferson-mello-olynyki).

Answer (score 0):

O PHP pode ficar desta forma:

```
$filtro = "Cadastro Iniciado,Aguardando aprovação de cadastro,Cadastro Aprovado,Carta Solicitada,Desistência de Cadastro,Carta Negada,Carta Cancelada,,,MS,MG,PA,PB,PR,PE,PI,RJ,RN,RS,RO,RR,SC,SP,"

$status = explode(',', $filtro);
$status_where = [];
foreach($status as $s) {
   $status_where[] = "'{$s}'";
}
$status_where = implode(',', $status_where);
```

Isso irá gerar um array com os itens `['Cadastro Iniciado','Aguardando aprovação de cadastro','MS']`

E com esse array montar sua query utilizando um `IN`

```
SELECT .. FROM report_partner_view WHERE ativo = 1 AND status_atual IN ($status)
```

Comment: ai que tá @Marcos, o "MS" nesse caso não é um status e sim um estado.

Comment: @gabrielfalieri Uma coisa que você pode fazer é considerar que as posições desse array sempre serão a mesma e montar sua query baseado nisso.